# Наиболее быстрое решение для нахождения диаметра графа

Tags: c#, алгоритм, графы

Решил задачу на codingame.com под название "Teads Sponsored Challenge", проходят все тесты, кроме четырех.

В этих четырех тестах по сравнению с остальными существенно увеличивается количество входных данных, а дают на входе количество ребер одним числом и в цикле - ребра (Вот так - "371 290", тип строковый). К слову, ребра перечисляются вразброс, то есть не отсортировано, 95 462, 461 364, 322 54, 300 359, 256 333, 64 157.

Я использовал двумерный массив, чтобы хранить ребра и написал рекурсивную функцию, чтобы проверять наличие соседей у вершин. Принцип работы программы следующий: собрал всю входную информацию, создал массив для хранения результата работы рекурсивной функции для каждой из вершин.

Но по таймауту не проходят остальные тесты, успевает обработать всего около 120 вершин, например из 546. Подозреваю, что проблема заключается в том, что я использую двумерный массив, как следствие при поиске соседей у вершины приходится обходить оба измерения массива.

Как можно сделать правильнее, лучше, быстрее?

К слову, код пишу в VS, а проверить выполнение тестов могу только на сайте, то есть написал код, скопировал и вставил в редактор кода на самом сайте, запустил тесты, получил результат. Отлаживать там можно только через Console.Error.WriteLine().

Comment: Воспользуйтесь профилировщиком, чтобы выделить наиболее затратные места в коде. Без точно поставленной задачи и примера кода нельзя сказать, что именно было сделано неправильно.

Comment: Думаю, проблема в алгоритме. Не надейтесь низкоуровневыми средствами решить проблему, если у вас алгоритм работает за `O(N^2)` вместо `O(log N)`. (Конкретнее сказать не могу, задание не видел.)

Comment: *"а проверить выполнение тестов могу только на сайте"*, тем не менее, Вы говорите, что *"В этих четырех тестах по сравнению с остальными существенно увеличивается количество входных данных"*. Соответственно, Вы можете локально сгенерировать необходимый тест и отладить программу.

Comment: Боюсь как-либо показывать задание, оно выглядит объемным, скопипастить - наругают. Своими словами...Попробую. Код показать могу.

Comment: В кратце, что именно нужно сделать на графе?

Comment: Есть сеть людей, надо передать сообщение как можно быстрее. Граф неориентированный, один человек передает сообщение за один час, неважно скольким людям, одному или нескольким. Надо вернуть минимальное количество часов за которое можно это сделать, только минимальное количество часов.

Comment: Ну найти самый длинный путь от первой вершины до всех, решается методом Дейкстры, если я правильно понял условие. Сложность n log n +m . до миллиона успеет.

Comment: Например, дано: 4 ребра. 0 1, 1 2, 2 3, 2 4. Если начать передавать сообщение из вершины 0, то это займет три часа, можно начать с 1 или 2, это займет два часа. Правильный ответ - два часа.

Comment: Максимальный тест какой?

Comment: Максимальный тест - количество ребер = 51865 .

Comment: а вершин? если меньше 1000 то за куб можно в лоб.

Comment: Входные данные: 
Количество ребер.
Далее перечисляются сами ребра в цикле.

Пока перечисляются ребра в цикле, нахожу самую большую вершину, для самого максимального теста она равна количеству ребер, то есть - 51865. Получается, что количество ребер совпадает с количеством вершин.

Comment: стоп! оно везде совпадает? т.е. вершин на 1 больше чем рёбер?

Comment: Посмотрел - да, везде совпадает, кроме десятого теста, там пропустили вершины под номерами 11 и 12, но с ними я разобрался.

Comment: Хотелось бы увидеть полностью задание и описание входных и выходных данных.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для решения этой задачи можно использовать следующий алгоритм (если конечно это действительно дерево)

1. прочитать о BFS
2. запустить BFS из 1 вершины, найти самую далёкую
3. Запустить из найденной, найти самую далекую.
4. вершины из пункта 2 и 3 - концы диаметра
5. найти вершину, лежащую на середине диаметра.
6. ответ - большее из расстояний от "центра" диаметра до крайних вершин диаметра

Сложность - O(M), точнее 2*M+N

Если нет, то ничего лучше чем запускать BFS из каждой вершины и выбирать минимум из максимумов не придумать.
Хорошее обсуждение на http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/4116?locale=ru

Answer (score 0):

```
iteration=0;
while(количество вершин в графе >2)
{
    посчитать количество ребер для каждой вершины;
    удалить все вершины, у которых всего одно ребро;
    iteration++;
}
```

Если количество вершин в графе 2, то `iteration++`;

Ответом будет `iteration`